# "Спасайся(,) кто может!"

Tags: фразеология, пунктуация

Хотелось бы знать, является ли выражение "спасайся(,) кто может" устойчивым выражением, то есть, нужна в нем запятая или нет?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасайся кто может - это цельное по смыслу выражение, и оно не выделяется знаками препинания. Об этом хорошо сказано  в справочнике Розенталя (§114. Цельные по смыслу выражения, 1.Запятая не ставится перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом в составе неразложимых сочетаний. См. http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/50.htm)
Данное правило основано на том, что фразеологический оборот не образует придаточного предложения и, как правило, эквивалентен члену предложения.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не ставится перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом в составе неразложимых сочетаний, например: сделать как следует (как полагается, как подобает), выполнить как должно (как надо, как нужно), хватать что подвернется, явиться как ни в чем не бывало, говорить что в ум взбредёт, добиваться во что бы то ни стало, приходить когда вздумается, спрятаться кто куда успел, не лезть куда не следует, ночевать где придется, делай что хочешь, бери что нравится, ***спасайся кто может***, есть что дают, будь что будет, идти куда глаза глядят, живите как знаете, приглашу к себе кого пожелаю, заплатил Бог знает сколько, кричит что есть мочи, рассказать все как есть, выдумывали кто во что горазд, достать что нужно (но: достать все, что нужно), черт знает что у них творится, городить черт знает что, поживиться чем можно, дать чего не жалко, картина чудо как хороша, страсть как интересно, ужас как трудно, беда как плохо.

(Розенталь; курсив мой - b-s)
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/50.htm

Answer (score 1):

Не нужна запятая. Только тут дело совсем не в фразеологичности **всего** оборота. "Кто может" - само по себе некоторый фразеологизм, как правило выполняет роль обычного подлежащего или дополнения.

Запятая не нужна не только в этом выражении, а вообще почти всегда в выражениях с "кто может", если это самое "кто может" не несет выраженного характера обращения и при отсутствии определяемого слова. Все потому, что "Кто может" - само по себе некоторый фразеологизм, как правило выполняет роль обычного подлежащего или дополнения.

*Танцует кто может. Работает кто может* - Запятые совсем не обязательны, даже не нужны.